How to implementing a Centered Marker Location Picker like Uber and Grab in React Native using Mapbox?
I am trying to implement a location picker functionality in React Native using Mapbox, similar to that of Uber or Grab, where the selected location is always at the center of the screen.
However, unlike the typical behavior, I want the selected location to remain unchanged even when zooming in or out, and only update when the map is dragged to a new location.
I found an example implementing this for the web here MapBox - Uber-like location picker but I can't find matching properties or methods in the Mapbox SDK for React Native.
Using this library https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps
